# reading the tex file in Python with many column

Tags: python, text

For reading the data file I have always used the following code

```
zx, Dx, sigx = np.genfromtxt('data/TEST.txt',unpack=True)
```

this txt file has 3 column and 1000 rows.

Now I have a text file with 3000 columns and 1000 rows like

```
zx, Dx, sigx, sigu, sigi, siga,..., 1000th_column
```

how should I read it while having option to call the values of any column I want?

because in previous code I called `zx[n]` but here the number of columns are to hight to define in the code.

thank you for your help

Comment: `tex` is not the same thing as "text". `tex` is program for formatting mathematics and exporting pdfs. `tex` was a precurser to `LaTeX`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will advice you to use `pandas` like this :

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data/TEST.txt', sep=",") # Change the seprarator to match your data
```

Then you can call call and row like this.

```py
df["zx"][n]
```

## Edit

If you want to read `column`890 and `row` 500 you do like this.

```py
df.iloc[500, 890]
```

[Here is documention](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) about `iloc`.

Comment: in this way how to do read the values of row 500 and column 890?

Comment: so could I do this? `a=df.iloc[i, j]` and `i` and `j` will be defined in `for loop`?

Comment: @MaY, Yes you could. `a=df.iloc[i, j].value`

Comment: it works without `value`, but it dosent read the first row. [0,0] gives me the first columns and second row

Comment: I don't understand your comment, why do you mean by "t dosent read the first row. [0,0] gives me the first columns and second row "